# MySqL filters only one id

Tags: php, mysql

I filter genres with mysql. But only those who have 22 id filters 22,23,24 in the form of those 22, but does not filter them.

Example, my genre_id column : 22,23,24 Not Show Filters
Example, my genre_id column : 22 Show Filters.

```
else if($_POST['lang_id']!=''  && $_POST['genre_id']!='')
  {
      $lang_id=$_POST['lang_id'];
      $genre_id=$_POST['genre_id'];

      $sql="SELECT tbl_language.`language_name`,tbl_movies.* FROM tbl_movies
          LEFT JOIN tbl_language ON tbl_movies.`language_id`= tbl_language.`id` 
          WHERE tbl_movies.`language_id`='$lang_id' AND FIND_IN_SET(tbl_movies.`genre_id`,$genre_id)
          ORDER BY tbl_movies.`id` DESC";
  }
  else if($_POST['lang_id']==''  && $_POST['genre_id']!='')
  {
      $genre_id=$_POST['genre_id'];
      $sql="SELECT tbl_language.`language_name`,tbl_movies.* FROM tbl_movies
          LEFT JOIN tbl_language ON tbl_movies.`language_id`= tbl_language.`id` 
          WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tbl_movies.`genre_id`,$genre_id)
          ORDER BY tbl_movies.`id` DESC";
  }
```

// MY Search Code

```
<div class="search_list" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px;float: left;margin-left: 20px">
                    <select name="genre_id" class="form-control" style="padding: 5px 10px;height: 40px;">
                      <option value="">--Genres--</option>
                      <?php 
                        $qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_genres ORDER BY gid DESC";
                        $res=mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
                        while ($info=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?=$info['gid']?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['genre_id']) && $_POST['genre_id']==$info['gid']){ echo 'selected';} ?>><?=$info['genre_name']?></option>
                          <?php
                        }
                        mysqli_free_result($res);
                      ?>
                    </select>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 5px 10px;height: 40px;margin-left: 10px;transform: none !important;"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Filtrele</button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: I think the parameters in `FIND_IN_SET(tbl_movies.\`genre_id\`,$genre_id)` are the wrong way round - try `FIND_IN_SET($genre_id, tbl_movies.\`genre_id\`)`

Comment: Good Job! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) the definition is...

> FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)

So the first one is the single value (22) and the second is the list (22,23,24), you are passing the parameters the wrong way round, so...

```
FIND_IN_SET(tbl_movies.`genre_id`,$genre_id)
```

should be

```
FIND_IN_SET($genre_id, tbl_movies.`genre_id`)
```